# Laravel+vue - Props is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

so I am new to vue, but getting up to speed. However, I cannot make the props thing to work - it always remains undefined in my child component.

The idea of the below is to create a app-wide notification modal window to display notifications.

This is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import ModalNotification from './components/Modal-Notification.vue';

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data : {
  formInputs: {},
  formErrors: {},
  showModal: false
},
components: {ModalNotification}
});
```

This is my Modal-Notification.vue

```
  <template>

  <transition name="modal">
      <div class="modal-mask" @click="$emit('close')">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div class="modal-container" @click.stop>

            <!-- <div class="modal-header">
              <slot name="header">
                NOTIFICATION
              </slot>
            </div> -->

            <div class="modal-body">
              <slot name="body">
                Bla bla
              </slot>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <slot name="footer">
                <button class="modal-default-button btn btn-success" @click="$emit('close')">
                  OK
                </button>
              </slot>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>

    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'ModalNotification',
        data: function() {
            return {
            };
        },
        props: ['showModal'],

        mounted: function() {
          console.log(this);
          document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            console.log(this.showModal);
            if (this.showModal && e.keyCode == 27) {
              this.$emit('close');
            }
          });
        },

        methods: {
        }
    }
    </script>
```

And the relevant part of app.blade.php

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
      <button @click="showModal = true" class="btn btn-default">MODAL</button>
      <modal-notification v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false" :showModal="false">
        <p slot="body" id="notification-message">hehe</p>
      </modal-notification>
      <div id="wrapper">
        @yield('sidebar')
        @yield('content')
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried everything out there, except switching to Browserify, babel and such stuff, but I don't think it should be needed - webpack should work just fine.

Please help, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in the following snippet of code:

```
  <modal-notification v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false" :showModal="false">
    <p slot="body" id="notification-message">hehe</p>
  </modal-notification>
```

`:showModal="false"` is basically shortcut of `v-bind:showModal="false"`, which tries to search vue instance variable in the value of attached HTML property([documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)). as you are passing `false` which is not a vue data variable, it is just passing `null` in `showModal` props.

If you want to pass only `false`, change the code to following:

```
  <modal-notification v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false" showModal="false">
    <p slot="body" id="notification-message">hehe</p>
  </modal-notification>
```

### Edited

I think it is magic of [camelCase-vs-kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case):

> HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:

You need to pass : `show-modal="false"`

```
  <modal-notification v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false" show-modal="false">
    <p slot="body" id="notification-message">hehe</p>
  </modal-notification>
```

Comment: Quick response, cool. But it still doesn't work - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9QQGCByXX4RcnNNZHNXTVFLMTA/view)
Also, why does it matter what the html template tag has assigned? What I want is for the app Vue instance to pass the data variable value to the child.

Comment: Lol, this is a step in the right direction. It's not longer undefined. However, it doesn't seem to be connected to the variable defined in the app Vue instance data - it seems to be just a static value - i.e. no matter if I open or close the modal, the value stays false. Any idea why?

Comment: And yes, I tried the v-bind with kebab-case as well, since the docs say this should pass a change in parent to the child, but it doesn't - [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props)

Comment: Actually reserved words like `false` and literals like `1` will be evaluated to the bool value false and the number 1 so I think that codes in `v-bind` are all evaluated as js code (only that variables are automatically added `this.`).